# SAXParser doesn't retrieves XML data from URL

Tags: java, xml, url, xml-parsing, saxparser

My implemented **SAXParser** class which uses **URL address** to process XML data does not returns the result. The class uses additional Currency class which in turn stores two variables `currId` and `rate` with setters/getters. When I run my class nothing shows up in java console. Here is the code:

```
public class MySAXParser extends DefaultHandler {

    private static List<Currencies> currencies = new ArrayList<Currencies>();
    private static Currencies curr = null;
    private static String text = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "http://nbt.tj/en/kurs/export_xml.php?date=2016-08-01&export=xmlout";

        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            MySAXParser handler = new MySAXParser();
            URL uri = new URL(url);
            sp.parse(new InputSource(uri.openStream()), handler);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Currencies curr : currencies) {
            System.out.println(curr.toString());
        }

    }

    public void startElement (String s, String s1, String elementName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("valute")) {
            curr = new Currencies();
            curr.setCurrId(atts.getValue("id"));
        }
    }

    public void endElement (String s, String s1, String element) throws SAXException {
        if (element.equals("valute")) {
            currencies.add(curr);
        }
        if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {
            curr.setRate(Double.parseDouble(text));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters (char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        text = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
    }

}
```

So, what I missed or doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does comparing `s1.equalsIgnoreCase` instead of the third parameter help?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, usage of second parameter `s1` also gives no result.

Comment: As far as I remember, SAX does not guarantee that a text node is reported as a single characters event so you need to improve that code as well. But as you say you don't get any result at all I am not sure what is wrong simply by reading the code. Step through with a debugger to check what's wrong if nobody comes along seeing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt that works fine with Java 1.8:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;


public class MySAXParser extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<Currency> currencies = new ArrayList<>();
    private Currency curr = null;
    private StringBuilder sb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "http://nbt.tj/en/kurs/export_xml.php?date=2016-08-01&export=xmlout";

        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            spf.setNamespaceAware(true);

            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            MySAXParser handler = new MySAXParser();

            sp.parse(new InputSource(url), handler);

            for (Currency curr : handler.getCurrencies()) {
                System.out.println(curr.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<Currency> getCurrencies() {
        return currencies;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String s, String localName, String elementName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("valute")) {
            curr = new Currency();
            currencies.add(curr);
            curr.setCurrId(atts.getValue("ID"));
        } else if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("value") || elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("CharCode")) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String s, String localName, String elementName) throws SAXException {
        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {
            curr.setRate(Double.parseDouble(sb.toString()));
            sb = null;
        }
        else if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("CharCode")) {
            curr.setCharCode(sb.toString());
            sb = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (sb != null) {
            sb.append(ch, start, length);
        }
    }

}
```

The class is

```
public class Currency {

    private String currId;

    /**
     * Get the value of currId
     *
     * @return the value of currId
     */
    public String getCurrId() {
        return currId;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of currId
     *
     * @param currId new value of currId
     */
    public void setCurrId(String currId) {
        this.currId = currId;
    }

        private double rate;

    /**
     * Get the value of rate
     *
     * @return the value of rate
     */
    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of rate
     *
     * @param rate new value of rate
     */
    public void setRate(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    private String charCode;

    /**
     * Get the value of charCode
     *
     * @return the value of charCode
     */
    public String getCharCode() {
        return charCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of charCode
     *
     * @param charCode new value of charCode
     */
    public void setCharCode(String charCode) {
        this.charCode = charCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Currency{" + "currId=" + currId + ", rate=" + rate + ", charCode=" + charCode + '}';
    }

}
```

A sample output I get is

```
Currency{currId=840, rate=7.8683, charCode=USD}
Currency{currId=978, rate=8.7448, charCode=EUR}
Currency{currId=960, rate=10.9395, charCode=XDR}
Currency{currId=156, rate=1.1828, charCode=CNY}
Currency{currId=756, rate=8.075, charCode=CHF}
Currency{currId=810, rate=0.1146, charCode=RUB}
Currency{currId=860, rate=0.2655, charCode=UZS}
Currency{currId=417, rate=1.1643, charCode=KGS}
Currency{currId=398, rate=0.2234, charCode=KZT}
Currency{currId=933, rate=3.9424, charCode=BYR}
Currency{currId=364, rate=0.2617, charCode=IRR}
Currency{currId=971, rate=1.139, charCode=AFN}
Currency{currId=586, rate=0.7504, charCode=PKR}
Currency{currId=949, rate=2.6076, charCode=TRY}
Currency{currId=934, rate=2.2481, charCode=TMT}
Currency{currId=826, rate=10.3618, charCode=GBP}
Currency{currId=36, rate=5.9162, charCode=AUD}
Currency{currId=208, rate=1.1755, charCode=DKK}
Currency{currId=352, rate=0.659, charCode=ISK}
Currency{currId=124, rate=5.9699, charCode=CAD}
Currency{currId=414, rate=26.004, charCode=KWD}
Currency{currId=578, rate=0.9193, charCode=NOK}
Currency{currId=702, rate=5.8215, charCode=SGD}
Currency{currId=752, rate=0.9136, charCode=SEK}
Currency{currId=392, rate=0.761, charCode=JPY}
Currency{currId=944, rate=4.9639, charCode=AZN}
Currency{currId=51, rate=1.6516, charCode=AMD}
Currency{currId=981, rate=3.3539, charCode=GEL}
Currency{currId=498, rate=0.3979, charCode=MDL}
Currency{currId=980, rate=0.317, charCode=UAH}
Currency{currId=784, rate=2.1421, charCode=AED}
Currency{currId=682, rate=2.0979, charCode=SAR}
Currency{currId=356, rate=1.175, charCode=INR}
Currency{currId=985, rate=2.0039, charCode=PLN}
Currency{currId=458, rate=1.9313, charCode=MYR}
Currency{currId=764, rate=0.2258, charCode=THB}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. Well usage of `s1` parameter and setting SAXParserFactory as namespace aware also give no result.

Comment: @Dozent, I have now found the time to fire up the Java IDE and test that code, it seems my earlier hint about the second parameter does not help as it is also empty if namespaces are not enabled, so above I have then used the third parameter as in the original code snippet.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works now. However I didn't get the idea why it works with `Valute, Value, ID` and not with `valute, value, id`.   Do you know why?

Comment: In XML, as in Java, the case of names matters, so you certainly need to use exactly the name of an attribute as given in the XML. So I had to correct the attribute access to extract the ID.